# TFS2017 (RTM): Unit test summary in build dont show actual test results

Tags: unit-testing, build-definition

After a build that runs c# unit tests, the number of test are shown but the test results of individual tests are not provided.[See](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BAIn4.png)

However the test results are published. See log. And are available when I search them in the test tab...

Finally here is the test task from the build definition:
[Build Definition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0HbP0.png)

Any Idea, what might be wrong?

Comment: The default output is to only show failed tests. On the English version there is a link on the right that shows failed that you can right click on to see the option of show all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which you got is correctly, cause you have selected  **failed** (English) in the **outcome** and you have no failed tests at all.

[image]

You just need to change the filter to **all** in outcome, you will get all tests shown.

[image]

Comment: Great. I didn't see the obvious.